# Create new oracle database: ORA-65008: missing or invalid SEED clause

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to create new database manually **(ORACLE 12.2.0)**.. but i'm getting this error `ORA-65008: missing or invalid SEED clause`..
the steps i followed:

1. creating new instance and connect into it
   [image]
2. then i tried to create the new database by this command :

CREATE DATABASE MONDBA 
USER sys IDENTIFIED BY sys 
USER system IDENTIFIED BY system
MAXLOGFILES 5
MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
MAXDATAFILES 200
MAXINSTANCES 1
MAXLOGHISTORY 500
LOGFILE  GROUP 1 ('C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\mondba\redo01a.rdo',
'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\mondba\redo01b.rdo') SIZE 50M,
GROUP 2 ('C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\mondba\redo02a.rdo',
'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\mondba\redo02b.rdo') SIZE 50M,
GROUP 3 ('C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\mondba\redo03a.rdo',
'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\mondba\redo03b.rdo') SIZE 50M
DATAFILE 'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\mondba\system01.dbf' SIZE 300M
 EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
SYSAUX
 DATAFILE 'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\mondba\sysaux01.dbf' SIZE 200M
UNDO TABLESPACE UNDOTBS1
DATAFILE 'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\mondba\undotbs01.dbf' 
SIZE 300M AUTOEXTEND OFF
DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP TEMPFILE 'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\mondba\temp01.dbf' SIZE 200M REUSE AUTOEXTEND OFF
CHARACTER SET WE8ISO8859P1
NATIONAL CHARACTER SET UTF8;

***and the result i get is:***
[image]

how can i fix this issue please ?!

Comment: We're mostly developers here; you'd rather try on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:
i added SEED clause to my query so it became like this:
CREATE DATABASE DBAF
USER sys IDENTIFIED BY sys
USER system IDENTIFIED BY system
MAXLOGFILES 5
MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
MAXDATAFILES 200
MAXINSTANCES 1
MAXLOGHISTORY 500
LOGFILE  GROUP 1 ('C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\redo01a.rdo',
'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\redo01b.rdo') SIZE 50M,
GROUP 2 ('C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\redo02a.rdo',
'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\redo02b.rdo') SIZE 50M,
GROUP 3 ('C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\redo03a.rdo',
'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\redo03b.rdo') SIZE 50M
DATAFILE 'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\system01.dbf' SIZE 300M EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
SYSAUX DATAFILE 'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\sysaux01.dbf' SIZE 200M
UNDO TABLESPACE UNDOTBS1
DATAFILE 'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\UNDOTBS1.dbf' 
SIZE 300M AUTOEXTEND OFF
DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP TEMPFILE 'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\temp01.dbf' SIZE 200M
 REUSE AUTOEXTEND OFF
CHARACTER SET WE8ISO8859P1
NATIONAL CHARACTER SET UTF8
ENABLE PLUGGABLE DATABASE 
SEED 
FILE_NAME_CONVERT = ('C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF', 
'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\pdbseed') 
SYSTEM DATAFILES SIZE 125M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED 
SYSAUX DATAFILES SIZE 100M 
USER_DATA TABLESPACE usertbs 
DATAFILE 'C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF\usertbs01.dbf' 
SIZE 100M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;

[image]

and i also created a folder named : **PDBSEED** in **C:\app\hamza\virtual\oradata\DBAF**
ps; DBAF is the folder that i create for new instance